# Apache POI XWPFParagraph length in twips or points

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

Apologies if I have overlooked something: is there a way to get the length in twips or points of the text that is held in an XWPFParagraph. I could achieve it using Font And FontMetrics separately but that seems clunky. Any help will be much appreciated.

i
I've searched what I hoped were the relevant Apache Javadocs.

Comment: What is intended to be achieved with this information? Let the word processing application render the paragraphs flowing across the pages as needed. Don't try to squeeze paragraphs into tight corsets.That contradicts how word processing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While calculating text length using font metrics may seem a bit cumbersome, it's a common approach across various libraries and frameworks. However, if you're looking for a potentially less clunky method within Apache POI specifically, you might consider using the Graphics2D class from AWT (Abstract Window Toolkit) for font metrics. Here's the implementation in a simplified example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class ParagraphLength {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(); // Your XWPFDocument instance
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph(); // Your XWPFParagraph instance
        
        // Set your text here
        String text = "Your text goes here";
        paragraph.createRun().setText(text);
        
        int fontSize = 12; // Change this to match your font size
        int twips = getTextLengthTwips(paragraph, fontSize);
        System.out.println("Text length in twips: " + twips);
        
        float points = twips / 20f; // 1 twip = 1/20 point
        System.out.println("Text length in points: " + points);
    }
    
    public static int getTextLengthTwips(XWPFParagraph paragraph, int fontSize) {
        Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB).getGraphics();
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
        graphics2D.setFont(font);
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = graphics2D.getFontMetrics();
        
        int totalWidth = 0;
        for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
            totalWidth += fontMetrics.stringWidth(run.text());
        }
        
        return totalWidth * 20; // Convert pixels to twips
    }
}
```

While it may not significantly reduce the clunkiness, it abstracts away some of the direct font manipulation and calculation, making the code slightly cleaner.

Comment: Oversimplified. What if different `XWPFRun`s have different fonts, different font families, different font sizes, not all plain but some bold, some italic, ... ? What if different scaling, character distance or kerning is used? ... And `return totalWidth * 20; // Convert pixels to twips`: Twip means **Tw**entieth of an **i**nch **p**oint. That is not the same as twentieth of a pixel.

Comment: @Luke Thank you for a comprehensive solution to my problem. I can use your code to solve my problem.

Comment: The app I'm working on generates a Wimbledon-type knockout competition draw; the end user has a choice of paper sizes, fonts etc for the output in the form of a Word table. I may need to use word wrap in the table depending of the longest length of the  competitor's names.
Thanks to both for your input.